# Firebird lock "table" to prevent inserts

Tags: transactions, locking, firebird

Is possible to lock a table to prevent inserts/updates/deletes ?

I need to lock a table, delete some records and "reset" a generator.

```
>> lock table logs to prevent inserts/updates/deletes;
delete from logs where id <= :lastIdProcessed;
if ((select count(1) from logs) = 0) {
    alter sequence logSequence restart with 0;
}
>> commit and release table
```

Another question is, I'll get in throwble if there is an `insert into logs (gen_id(logSequence,1))` waiting for the lock release, the insert will run with the `logSequence` incremented using its value before it `restart`?

Comment: switch all the database to no-connections-but-SYSDBA mode, clear the table, reset the generator, switch database back to working mode

Comment: you may put a trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE that unconditionally causes error like division by zero, that would preclude any data added. However that is "ugly hack"

Comment: you may take all your users/roles/procedures and revoke their security rights to modify the table

Comment: but all in all this seems a rather unreasonable idea, why would anyone ever want it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can start a snapshot table stability transaction with table reservation using

```
SET TRANSACTION 
    READ WRITE 
    ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY 
    WAIT
    RESERVING <tablename>, <tablename> FOR PROTECTED WRITE
```

> #### SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY Isolation Level
>
> The `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` isolation level is the most
> restrictive. As in `SNAPSHOT`, a transaction in
> `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` isolation sees only those changes that were committed
> before the current transaction was started. After a
> `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` is started, no other transactions can make any changes to
> any table in the database that has changes pending. Other transactions
> are able to read other data, but any attempt at inserting, updating or
> deleting by a parallel process will cause conflict exceptions.
>
> The `RESERVING` clause can be used to allow other transactions to
> change data in some tables.
>
> If any other transaction has an uncommitted change of data pending in
> any database table before a transaction with the
> `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` isolation level is started, trying to start a
> `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` transaction will result in an exception.
>
> [..]
>
> #### RESERVING
>
> The `RESERVING` clause in the `SET TRANSACTION` statement reserves
> tables specified in the table list. Reserving a table prevents other
> transactions from making changes in them or even, with the inclusion
> of certain parameters, from reading data from them while this
> transaction is running.
>
> A `RESERVING` clause can also be used to specify a list of tables that
> can be changed by other transactions, even if the transaction is
> started with the `SNAPSHOT TABLE STABILITY` isolation level.
>
> One `RESERVING` clause is used to specify as many reserved tables as
> required.

See [Transaction Statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-transacs-statements) for more information; you might also want to consult the old Interbase 6.0 documentation (especially Embedded SQL Guide and Developer's guide, see https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ at end) for information.

I have no experience using this feature, so I can't advise you on its potential pitfalls.